# Select by Attribute on a changing date

Tags: arcpy, query, select-by-attribute, date

I want to be able to select by attributes for dates that change weekly. I have gotten an invalid expression error for the follow script where the date needs to change to the current date and the same date just the following year every time I run it. I want to be able to create a model with multiple versions of this script.

```
import arcpy
in_layer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
in_field = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
one_date = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
two_date = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)

new_selection = "NEW_SELECTION"
where_clause = "in_field >= date 'one_date 00:00:00' AND in_field <= date 'two_date 00:00:00'"

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(in_layer, new_selection, where_clause)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using strings when you want to be using the variable.

Try:

```
where_clause = "in_field >= date '{} 00:00:00' AND in_field <= date '{} 00:00:00'".format (one_date, two_date)
```